# USB Pcap Wireshark - ''1.1.3'' What this address mean?

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I am exploring the world of USB packet capturing.
after a capture session from my USB SubZero device 
I understand the data captured but don't understand the address.

Wireshark say '1.1.3' in the address and USB URB in other field.Is not a COM port like i hope it would be cause in effect
in device manager The SUBZERO is not recognized with a COM port and is under the AUDIO,GAMES... peripherics.

What to do if I want to send data to this address.